# BIC to choose lambda in lasso regression

Tags: r, lasso-regression

I know we can use GCV value to choose lambda in lasso regression. Can we also use BIC value to choose lambda in lasso regression? And how could I calculate BIC value with glmnet() in R?. I have read many lecture notes and they are all talking about using GCV value to choose the appropriate lambda.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Please expand it at the point where you're having a programming problem. Otherwise I suggest crossvalidated.com

Comment: Actually, I am doing a simulation study. I just want to use BIC value to choose lambda instead of GCV value. I know how to do lasso regression with lambda chosen by GCV. I just don't know how to implement lasso regression with the lambda chosen by BIC value in R.